# How to check the number of times particular row with text is visible using cypress?

Tags: cypress

i wanted to assert the number of times the table row with text is visible using cypress.

below is html,

```
<div data-testid="container">
    <div data-testid="body">
        <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-0">
            <div role="cell">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div role="table-cell-row-0-column-name" role="cell">
                <button type="button" data-testid="expand-row"></button>
                "Parent 1"
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-0.0">
            <div role="cell">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div role="table-cell-0.0-column-name>
                <button type="button" data-testid="expand-row"></button>
                Child 1 of Parent 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-0.1">
            <div role="cell">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div role="table-cell-0.1-column-name>
                <button type="button" data-testid="expand-row"></button>
                Child 2 of Parent 1
            </div>
        </div>

        <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-1">
            <div role="cell">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div data-testid="table-row-1-column-name">
                <button type="button" data-testid="expand-row"></button>
                Parent 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="row" data-testid="table-row-1.0">
            <div role="cell">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div data-testid="table-row-1.0-column-name">
                <button type="button" data-testid="expand-row"></button>
                Child 1 of Parent 2
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now for the above html code, how can i check if the text "Child 1 of Parent 1" exists only once in the table using cypress.

Could someone help me with this. I am new to using cypress. In the process of learning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
cy.get('div[role="row"]')
  .find('div:nth-child(2)')
  .filter(':contains("Child 1 of Parent 2")')
  .should('have.length', 1)
```

So inside your `div[role="row"]` yo have two div's and the scond div contains your desired text. Since there are no attribute value pair which is common in all the second div's hence I have used `div:nth-child(2)`.

After executing it locally, I found that you can directly use:

```
cy.get('div[role="row"]')
  .filter(':contains("Child 1 of Parent 2")')
  .should('have.length', 1)
```

[image]

Comment: @SteveZodiac yes I just found that.

Comment: @SteveZodiac Ya just saw it. Updated my answer.

Comment: this seems to be working for above html. but the text can be sometimes first child , second child.

Comment: You can use the second snippet in that case where we are directly using `filter()` after `cy.get(‘div[role=“row”]’)`.

Comment: cy.get(div[role="row"] returns the first div element with role="row". but this fails if i am checking for the text which is second or third div element with role="row"

Comment: `cy.get(div[role="row"]` will get all the 5 divs and not just the 1st div and then `.filter(':contains("Child 1 of Parent 2")')` will check inside all of these 5 div's. You can check this image - https://imgur.com/a/M8ZzZ04. One case that I could think of is that the other div's doesn't have the `role="row"`.